# A proper way to push log from S3 to AWS CloudWatch using Lambda and S3 Event notification

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I wrote a Lambda function that will get triggered by multiple S3 notifcation based on the prefix in S3 object. My idea is that new log object is created then create new logstream then push the log the new logstream, but there is a posibility that my lambda got invoke many time since S3 contain multiple env logs so I also implementing this `cloudwatch.check_logstream_exsited()` to make sure that I don't have to create new logstream when multiple invocation happen at the same time and push to the existing logstream, only create new logstream when a certain second/minutes is passed.

My problem is I was getting `[ERROR] ResourceAlreadyExistsException: An error occurred (ResourceAlreadyExistsException) when calling the CreateLogStream operation: The specified log stream already exists` when many invocation started

Here is my lambda code:

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import gzip
import os
import cloudwatch
import datetime
import random
import string
import json, requests

current_milli_time = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

log_group_name = None
cloudwatch_logs = boto3.client('logs')

evenlist = os.environ['EVENT_LIST'].split(",")
log_group_list = os.environ['LOG_GROUP_LIST'].split(",")

# Generate the current date in the format: YYYY/MM/DD
current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

# Generate a random string of 10 characters
random_string = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=32))
# Combine the elements to create the final string
new_log_stream_name = f"{current_date}/[$LATEST]{random_string}"

old_log_stream_name = None
target_logstream_name = None
target_log_group = None
log_stream_status = None

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    s3event = event['Records'][0]['s3']['configurationId']
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    compressed_content = response['Body'].read()
    decompressed_content = gzip.decompress(compressed_content).decode('utf-8')

    for i, event_type in enumerate(evenlist):
        if s3event == event_type:
            target_log_group = log_group_list[i]
            filtered_old_logstream_name = cloudwatch.check_logstream_exsited(log_group_list[i])
            if filtered_old_logstream_name != new_log_stream_name:
                print(f"Logstream {new_log_stream_name} is newer than {filtered_old_logstream_name}")
                cloudwatch.create_new_logstream(log_group_list[i], new_log_stream_name)
                log_stream_status = True
                target_logstream_name = new_log_stream_name
                cloudwatch.push_log(log_group_list[i], new_log_stream_name, decompressed_content)
            else:
                target_logstream_name = filtered_old_logstream_name
                log_stream_status = False
                print(f"LogStream {filtered_old_logstream_name} existed")
                cloudwatch.push_log(log_group_list[i], filtered_old_logstream_name, decompressed_content)
                
    json_data = {
        "s3-event": s3event,
        "bucket": bucket,
        "object": key,
        "log-group": target_log_group,
        "log-stream": target_logstream_name,
        "new-log-stream": log_stream_status
    }
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json_data
    }
```

cloudwatch code:

```
import boto3
import time

current_milli_time = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))
cloudwatch_logs = boto3.client('logs')

def push_log (log_group,log_stream,content):
    log_event = {
        'timestamp': current_milli_time(),
        'message': content
    }
    # Put the log event to the log stream
    #print(f"Push Log to {log_group}")
    response = cloudwatch_logs.put_log_events(
        logGroupName=log_group,
        logStreamName=log_stream,
        logEvents=[log_event]
    )

def check_logstream_exsited (log_group):
    logstream_name = cloudwatch_logs.describe_log_streams(
        logGroupName=log_group,
        descending = True,
        orderBy='LastEventTime'
    )
    #print(logstream_name['logStreams'][0]['logStreamName'])
    filtered_logstream_name = logstream_name['logStreams'][0]['logStreamName']
    #print (f"Latest logstream from console: {filtered_logstream_name}")
    return filtered_logstream_name

def create_new_logstream (log_group,logstream):
    cloudwatch_logs.create_log_stream(
        logGroupName=log_group, 
        logStreamName=logstream
    )
    print(f"Logstream {logstream} created")
```

I tried the workaround to use a `try except` to handle the error so it always push to the old logstream like this:

```
    try:
        for i, event_type in enumerate(evenlist):
            if s3event == event_type:
                target_log_group = log_group_list[i]
                filtered_old_logstream_name = cloudwatch.check_logstream_exsited(log_group_list[i])
                if filtered_old_logstream_name != new_log_stream_name:
                    print(f"Logstream {new_log_stream_name} is newer than {filtered_old_logstream_name}")
                    cloudwatch.create_new_logstream(log_group_list[i], new_log_stream_name)
                    log_stream_status = True
                    target_logstream_name = new_log_stream_name
                    cloudwatch.push_log(log_group_list[i], new_log_stream_name, decompressed_content)
                else:
                    target_logstream_name = filtered_old_logstream_name
                    log_stream_status = False
                    print(f"LogStream {filtered_old_logstream_name} existed")
                    cloudwatch.push_log(log_group_list[i], filtered_old_logstream_name, decompressed_content)
    except cloudwatch_logs.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
        log_stream_status = False
        target_logstream_name = filtered_old_logstream_name
        print("Error LogStream existed pushing to old logstream")
        cloudwatch.push_log(target_log_group, filtered_old_logstream_name, decompressed_content)
        print("Pushed")
```

And it seems to work but always show error count in the lambda metrics.

I also thinking of just always create new logstream when new log is put in S3, this is my last resort if I can't find any solution to fix this issue.